# Get Dropdown list value from database based on date i picked using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html.dropdownlistfor

I need to change dynamically dropdown list values based on date value by ajax.?

This is my code

```
    <div class="span3">
                                          <label>Bill Date 
                                           <div class="span12">
                                             <div class="input-append date" id="dp2" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                                <input class="span6" type="text" readonly="readonly" name='billdate' value="<?php echo $date1; ?>"/> <span class="add-on" disabled><i class="splashy-calendar_day" ></i></span> 
                                             </div>
                                            </div>
                                            </label>
                                       </div>
    <div class="span2" id="txtHintbill" style=" margin-left:85px;">
                                        <label>Mode:</label>
                                        <select name="mode" class="span10" onChange="billno(this.value)">
                                                  <option value="">Select Mode</option>
                                                  <option value="CASH" selected>CASH</option>
                                                  <option value="CREDIT">CREDIT</option>
                                                 <!--  <option value="CHEQUE">CHEQUE</option> -->
                                                  </select>
                                    </div>
```

My script code is

```
  <script>
   function billno(str)
    {
    var xmlhttp;    
    if (str=="")
      {
      document.getElementById("").innerHTML="";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("txtHintbill").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","billno.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

And my billno.php file is

```
<?php
include"config.php";
$m=$_GET["q"];
?>
<?php
$con=mysql_query("SELECT billno FROM printhub1 WHERE date1='$m' AND cash_detail='Not Received' ORDER BY billno");
$num=mysql_num_rows($con);
if($num==1)
{
?>
<select name="billno" id="billno" >
<?php

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($con))
{
    $billno=$row['billno'];
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $billno; ?>" <?php echo $billno; ?> ><?php echo $billno; ?></option>
    <?php
}
    ?>
</select>
<?php
}
?>
```

I would to replace the select tag content.

I have already tried value retrieved and show in textbox, but i don't know how to get full dropdown list values.

Comment: Any code you already tried implementing? If not, good luck :)

Comment: This is not a "Throw the code at me" forum. But we will help you fix problems with code you have already written and tried.

Comment: I tried, whether i selected some value form dropdown, it will replicate another dropdown list using ajax. Now this logic, i can't guess how to do it.

Comment: How much insight were you expecting from a one sentence post and no code provided?

Comment: Seems like you need to invest more time and effort in learning code, or hire a developer.

Comment: Just tell your suggestion, i don't need full code.

Comment: you won't get much help without providing a better explanation of the problems you have and code you attempted to solve it with

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions...

1. Implement AJAX using jQUERY (since you have already tagged the post with jQuery, I wonder why are you not using it). This will make the entire `xmlhttp` thing easier for you under `billno()` function.
2. If you want to change the dropdown list dynamically based on date value entered in the text box, then you need to call the `onChange()` in the date input box (`<input class="span6" type="text"  name='billdate'`) - because when this value in this input box changes, you fire the AJAX.
3. Write the line `<option value="<?php echo $billno; ?>" <?php echo $billno; ?> ><?php echo $billno; ?></option>` as below:

`<option value="<?php echo $billno; ?>"><?php echo $billno; ?></option>`

4. You need a mechanism to refresh your `<SELECT>` based on the reply from your AJAX call. I suggest you use jQuery for updating the `<select>`. Example,

   $.post ("billno.php", { q : str }, function (data) { 
            $("#txtHintbill").html (data); 
   });

Above code will perform the AJAX post as well as update the HTML of the div ID `txtHintbill` with results from server.

Hope this gives you some direction to move forward.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Mr.hashbrown, i will try it that way.

Comment: No problem, if the answer helps you - you may upvote the answer or choose it as answer by clicking the tick